# Passing Multiple URL's for OKhttp url Request type

Tags: java, okhttp

Is there any way to Passing Multiple URL's for OKhttp url Request type. Actually i want pass multi url's like website, mobile request urls(Androd, mobile browser, tablet)

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
   .url("multi url" + ---
   .addheader(---).build();
```

Comment: What do you want to do, precisely? Why are you trying to add "multi urls" to a single `Request` object?

Comment: I want to compare the data on the pages (page could be website, native app, mobile browser, tablet browser)

Comment: Then you need to make several requests. So create one `Request` per URL you want to check.

Comment: Yes..that is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

The OkHttp `Request` object allows one and only one URL.

If you require several requests, create different requests:

```
Request stackoverflowRequest = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://www.stackoverflow.com/")
  .addHeader(...)
  .build();
Request googleRequest= new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://www.google.com/")
  .addHeader(...)
  .build();
```

If you don't want to write all the headers X times, you can use the following:

```
Request templateRequest = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://www.example.com/")
  .addHeader(...)
  .build();
Request stackoverflowRequest = templateRequest.newBuilder()
  .url("https://www.stackoverflow.com/")
  .build();
Request googleRequest = templateRequest.newBuilder()
  .url("https://www.google.com/")
  .build();
```